# Best range speed

Tags: aircraft-performance

I understand that the best L/D gives best range however, I have read that Carson speed is the most economical cruising speed where the ratio fuel flow/knot of airspeed reaches a minimum. I have read on a site that an increase in 16% in fuel flow will give a about a 31% increase in my speed.
My question is why this speed doesn’t give a better range than best range speed
Hypothetically, if I increase fuel flow by 20% and this gives me 20% increase in speed this should give me the same range as best range speed right! So if a 16% increase in fuel flow gives a 31% increase in speed this should give a better range in spite of a slight increase in drag or have I got this all wrong.

Comment: These number pairs you’re quoting are at specific points on a specific curve. They are not valid at any other point.

Comment: That site is wrong. The fuel flow (mass per time, proportional to power) will increase by more than 50%, but the total fuel used for flying a given distance will only increase by 16%, because you take ~30% less time to cover that distance.

Comment: Ok. This is my question. If total fuel used for a given distance will only increase by 16%  for a 30 knot increase in airspeed why don’t I get a greater range at Carson speed than at best range speed.